# uninstall a manually compiled package in unix

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, unix, imagemagick, rmagick

I have installed imagemagick by downloading and compiling the source.how to correctly uninstall the ImageMagick that was manually installed in order to installed rmagick gem.
Is there something like "make uninstall".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no standard procedure.

Sometimes makefiles provide an `uninstall` rule you can run in order to remove files installed by `install`.

If Imagemagick doesn't provide any *tool* to uninstall itself you'll have to manually remove it by removing the files it installed.

Comment: That mean I can safely just delete the files?

Comment: @mohit: yes, in Linux there's not something like windows' registry, when you install an application it just puts its files in system directories. (Well, some big applications also modify system configuration files, but that's not the case for Imagemagick)

Comment: Presuming you installed to local as you should have then in all probability you can `rm -rf /usr/local/lib/ImageMagick* /usr/local/share/ImageMagick*` to get rid of most of it. The actual binaries will be in /usr/local/bin and will need to be removed separately.

Comment: Note that ImageMagik makes a whole pile of binaries. If you still have the build directory, try `make -n install 2>&1 > temp.txt` and look through the output to learn what the installation did...

Answer (score 0):

Imagemagick provides standard uninstall procedure if you have compiled it from source.

```
1. cd source_dir
2. make uninstall
```

From docs:

> **make uninstall**
>
> Remove all files from the system which are (or would
>   be) installed by sudo make install using the current configuration.
>   Note that this target is imperfect for PerlMagick since Perl no longer
>   supports an uninstall target.